# how to draw horizontal and vertical lines in android shape

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, drawable

I am trying to draw vertical and horizontal lines in a rectangle in android.
My code is ready to draw a rectangle, but I'm having trouble with horizontal and vertical lines

**my code for drawing a rectangle**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rectangle_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#0000FF"  />
    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

[image]

I'm trying to draw the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `ConstraintLayout` then try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:padding="10dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/lay_bg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And if you want to do something individual in that box then try [GridView](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gridview-in-android-with-example) or `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` check [this](https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example)

Note:  `android:background="@drawable/lay_bg"` its your drawable for rectangle

If you want to try with `LinearLayout` try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/lay_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0000FF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0000FF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Output for both code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqhXD.jpg)